# Legal issues when forking Lua?

Tags: licensing, lua

I've been developing a highly modified version of Lua (including a rewrite of the sources to keep a better maintainability). Right now i'm at a point where I would consider forking Lua, and possibly re-release it under a different name (so people don't mistake it as the original Lua interpreter).

Of course the resulting Interpreter and compiler will be Opensource (MIT License, just as Lua5.0). but I wonder if that would be just fine with the Lua license? Can I use the Lua sources to continue my own work? do I have to keep the copyright notes?

Comment: Since you plan to release your code, is there any reason not to offer your work to the upstream developers? Then you'll have less to maintain independently on your own version.

Comment: @Novelocrat: see my comment to Javiers answer

Comment: @Novelocrat: The Lua Team takes ideas and feedback from the outside, but not code.

Comment: I'm interested on this. Please update your question / comment here when you go public with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to send an email to the Lua folks. I'm 99,9% sure you won't have any problem.

Now that I think about it, another guy create a language called "Idle" which, if I remember well, is heavily based on Lua.

As long as you properly show the due credits and fairly represent the differences with Lua, I'm sure you'll be fine.

Comment: Contacting the Lua folks sounds like a good Idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 'polite' thing to do is to use a different name and clearly credit on your documentation; stating that it's based on Lua but not 'official' Lua.  AFAIK, the licence doesn't legally require even that; but it's what you're expected to do.

[Remo.D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321285/legal-issues-when-forking-lua/3321330#3321330) mentioned the Idle case; personally, i don't like the attitude of "this fixes the problems with Lua" that i kinda read on Idle's webpage and his messages to the Lua list; but it's widely recognized that he's doing the right thing: a different name and openly showing credits.

If you want to be really popular in the Lua community; you could try to release your code not as a fork of Lua; but as a set of patches to the core.  It's more work, I'm sure; but it has a much higher chance of being used by more people; and maybe (big maybe) some ideas could eventually be integrated in the core.

Comment: releasing it as a set of patches won't work since i'm using an entirely different type of code indentation - the whole source tree would be one single patch... besides that, I'm implementing things that would neve make it into the Lua core, such as try-case statements, native classes, etc. So i'll probably stick with the option mentioned by Remo.D. I like the Idea though, so +1

Comment: It's easy enough to take a diff with whitespace differences ignored. Once relevant patches are applied by them, they can always run `indent` or whatever to get the code in their preferred style.

Comment: @Novelocrat: even if that would be possible (which I doubt), there is still the try-case (etc) stuff, which simply won't be accepted by the Lua team.

Comment: still, if you want it to be used, a patch is less 'heretic' than a fork.  of course, if user base is low in your set of goals, then the extra work might not be worth it.